# Convert array of objects to the object, with keys based on object keys?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

For example, in my Mongo Aggregate request I'm getting the array, which consists of two objects:

```
[
  {
    "key": "first",
    "meta": 123,
  },
  {
    "key": "second",
    "meta": 567,
    "maybeonmorefield": 789
  }
]
```

Is it possible to convert this array to the following object by using only Mongo aggregation framework:

```
{
  "first": {
    "meta": 123,
  },
  "second": {
    "meta": 123,
    "maybeonmorefield": 789
  }
}
```

As you see, the keys are actually the `key` field values from the objects in the first examples.

Thanks for any tips :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to re-arrange your documents on root level and [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to build new keys dynamically:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            "root": "$$ROOT"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "root.key": 0,
            "root._id": 0
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: [[ { k: "$key", v: "$root" } ]]
            }            
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_CnlpTd7VWU)